# PayPal, How to connect payments to specific item or service in app?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment-processing

This question is mostly about architectural implementation of PayPal integration. I think this question is for any platforms which will use PayPal services.

I have client application, where multiple items and services are being sold. These items and services should be transferred immediatly to user. Which means I need to use immediate payment.

When user wants to buy item or service, client will open PayPal's windows to authorize this payment. When payment completed successfully user's client application will receive from PayPal unique `payment id` which looks like this:

```
PAY-123345ABCEFG678
```

The only fields which are connected to my item or service, which are fetched from this `payment id` are `total sum` and  `description`

How it is possible to connect my item or service in my application to specific user, who bought it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you manage payments via your app server 
(https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/payments/)
you can do that this way:

1. Make your Payment object
2. Set redirect urls:

   ```
   RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();

   redirectUrls.setReturnUrl( *yourSiteReturnUrl* + "/" + *yourItemID* ); // add item ID
   ```

Then, when user confirms payment he will be redirected to that URL `returnUrl` with params that PayPal provided (`paymentId` and `PayerID`) and `yourItemID`. 
Then you call your server and pass it `paymentId`, `PayerID` and `yourItemID` to execute actual payment with `paymentId` and do whatever with  `yourItemID`